# Vim writes some special charecters in insert mode

Tags: vim, vi

When I use vim recently, I observe that the insert mode in vim doesn't work properly as I expect. As I switch the applications by using the shortcut `Alt-Tab` or `Cmd-tab`, vim writes `[O` in to buffer. Same thing happens when I switch back to the terminal(vim), vim writes `[I` into the buffer, I can't find a good keyword to find the right solution, so can someone give me a solution, a keyword or a hint please?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Have you mapped any special keys? E.g. capslock to escape etc? I vaguely remember reading this could cause such problems....

Comment: not at all, i mapped only usual keys like jj or <c-j>

Comment: hmm, I don't have much idea - a similar thing happened to me but it got resolved accidentally while working on a [different problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683659/in-tmux-on-remote-machine-each-new-line-in-terminal-is-indented-to-the-end-of-t/684526#684526). I hope this helps you!